# Running a Kotlin github repository from the command line

Tags: java, kotlin, github, svg, command-line

I am trying to run this github repository :https://github.com/maltaisn/svg-equations

I have no prior experience with kotlin (although I have used java before).
I followed the instructions in the readme file and downloaded the packages and the .jar. My problem is that the output files it generates are always blank. The .jar file, .svg file, and the zip (and unzipped version) of the repository are all in the same folder.

I think the problem has to do with the .jar file not being able to find the actual source code but I do not know how to resolve this. Logically I should have to provide the path to the code folder somewhere but I don't know how to do this.

Here's the command line instruction I'm using: `java -jar svgeq-release.jar <inksc_test.svg>`
(my .svg is called inksc_test.svg and is just a simple circle)

Files I am using: "Assets" in v1.1.0 https://github.com/maltaisn/svg-equations/releases

[My input .svg file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q7c_C_yBqP3DbDst1Y6h5YCyWExMWvfs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There are no path elements in your input file and the library's documentation says it only works on path elements.